# Passing variables through locate_template

Tags: get-template-part, include

While I've typically used `include` or `require` on their own to save long term code maintenance I've started to use `get_template_part` and `locate_template` as using built in WordPress stuff is always best.

My question is are you supposed to be able to pass variables through to the results of either `get_template_part` or `locate_template`?

```
<?php
$var = get_option( 'my-custom-option' );

get_template_part( 'custom-template-part' );
?>
```

In the code above the `$var` would be printed inside the custom template but the variable doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something or is this expected behaviour?

I've found that they don't pass in the instance above or when using locate_template

```
<?php
locate_template( 'custom-template-part.php', true );
?>
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Like [MathSmath wrote](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4462/passing-variables-through-locate-template/4466#4466), [get_template()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template) does not support the re-use of your variables.

But [locate_template()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template) infact does no inclusion at all. It just locates a file for inclusion.

So you can make use of [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) to have this working just like you expect it:

```
include(locate_template('custom-template-part.php'));
```

`$var` from your example can be used in the template part then.

A related question with a more technical explanation of the variable scope and get_template(): [Form Submitting Error with get_template_part()](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1779/form-submitting-error-with-get-template-part)

Comment: Good call. I didn't notice that locate_template() has a param that lets you optionally call load_template() with the results (which get_template_part does), or just return them. I'm looping back on a current project to update code using this approach...thanks!

Comment: shortly after I posted here I ended up using the same method.

Comment: [21676](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21676) addresses this, but doesn't look like it'll be committed.

Comment: Maybe Im wrong but: `locate_template()` infact **does** inclusion, if the parameter is set as `true` -as in the question. (default is `false`, so dont paste the questions version into accepted answer.) You could also just use `set_query_var('var', $var);` and use your `get_template_part()` as normal. Then you also have the default Worpdress variables accessible within the templatefile, as @MathSmath mentioned.

Answer (score 14):

A neat solution found in the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part#Passing_Variables_to_Template)

So if you are looping thru custom posts, you can do this:

```
foreach ($custom_posts as $custom_post) {
    set_query_var( 'my_post', $custom_post );
    get_template_part( 'content', 'part' );
}
```

And in that template itself, you will automatically get a `$my_post`.

Comment: This would be the correct answer if the example code was answering the question. (Passing option, not complete posts array)

Comment: This works beautifully to pass extra information to the included template. It also works for `wc_get_template_part` in WooCommerce which no doubt extends default WP.

Answer (score 9):

I've had trouble with this too (while trying to get a custom query to work with a template part). The short answer is: no, the template part doesn't automatically inherit custom vars the way a regular include does.

Both get_template_part() and locate_template() eventually use the load_template() function to actually load the file (using a require). This function globalizes the following vars:

$posts, $post, $wp_did_header, $wp_did_template_redirect, $wp_query, $wp_rewrite, $wpdb, $wp_version, $wp, $id, $comment, $user_ID

However, no other vars appear to be available from inside the template part. I guess since the actual require is wrapped in a function, the scope changes or something?

Anyhoo, I'd try globalizing any additional vars you need to pass, then calling up those globals from your template part.

Answer (score 5):

Just my two cents for future references, a workaround at least in Wordpress 3.5 is to add the variable to `$wp_query->query_vars`.

I needed my global `_vk_errors` inside a template part and just did `$wp_query->query_vars['_vk_errors'] = $_vk_errors;` before calling `get_template_part()`.

Answer (score 4):

### **Wordpress 5.5+**

The **$args** parameter was added to `locate_template`
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/locate_template/

**Pass data**

```
$data = [
  'foo' => 'Hello',
  'bar' => ', Wordpress 5.5',
];
locate_template('your-template.php', true, true, $data);
```

**your-template.php**

```
//handle passed arguments through $args
echo $args['foo'] . $args['bar']; // "Hello, Wordpress 5.5"
// or use extract($args);
extract($args);
echo $foo . $bar; // "Hello, Wordpress 5.5"
```

`locate_template` uses `load_template`, that since 5.5 can pass additional arguments to the template as well.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/load_template/

So do all the template functions that use `locate_template`:

`get_header`, `get_footer`, `get_sidebar`, `get_template_part`.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_header/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_footer/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_sidebar/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/

Answer (score 2):

There is my simple function solving variable problem. It's doing same thing as Wordpress do in `get_template_part()` function. Just copy and paste to `function.php`

```
function getTemplatePart($slug = null, $name = null, array $params = array()) {
    global $posts, $post, $wp_did_header, $wp_query, $wp_rewrite, $wpdb, $wp_version, $wp, $id, $comment, $user_ID;

    do_action("get_template_part_{$slug}", $slug, $name);
    $templates = array();
    if (isset($name))
        $templates[] = "{$slug}-{$name}.php";

    $templates[] = "{$slug}.php";

    $_template_file = locate_template($templates, false, false);

    if (is_array($wp_query->query_vars)) {
        extract($wp_query->query_vars, EXTR_SKIP);
    }
    extract($params, EXTR_SKIP);

    require($_template_file);
}
```

Example of usage in template

```
$params = array(
    'utm_source' => 'footer'
);
while ($posts->have_posts()) {
    $posts->the_post(); 
    getTemplatePart('content', 'heighlight', $params);
}
```

In the `content-heighlight.php` is accessible variable with name `$utm_source` and value `footer`

Comment: Interesting function. Are all the globals and query vars usually accessible in normal template files?

Answer (score 0):

You can just wrap the get_template_part, store a model object in a global var, and clear it later. Here is how we have been doing in our projects:

**functions.php**

```
$model = null; // this is a global variable 
function my_get_template_part($slug, $name = null, $templateModel = null) {
    global $model;
    $model = $templateModel; // set the global var to the provided model object
    get_template_part($slug,$name); 
    $model = null; // clear the global var
}

function get_model() {
    global $model;
    return $model;
}
```

**Usage in the main template:**

```
<?php my_get_template_part('template-parts/xxxx','xxx',array('test1'))?>
```

**Accessing the provided model in the template-part :**

```
<?php $model = get_model() ?>
```

This way, you don't have to copy & paste the original get_template_part function to your own function in case its implementation may change later by WP developers.