# Why does get_template_part() break variables?

Tags: include

In PHP, when you `include` a file, the variables you're using in your current scope are available for use in the included file.

When using WordPress's `get_template_part()`, variables are no longer available in the "included" file.

`get_template_part()` calls `locate_template()` which then calls `load_template()`, which then performs the `require` or `require_once`.

If WordPress eventually calls PHP's `require`, why do the variables no longer work? Is it something to do with the 3 function calls before the actual `require`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4462/passing-variables-through-locate-template

Comment: @czerspalace That seems like a "How to" and this sounds like a "Why does" type question.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee got it. Should I delete my comment?

Comment: @czerspalace Nah, the community could agree and close the question as dup. I just thought the two were different in principle.

Comment: Files included inside a function get the scope of that function. That'll probably get flagged as low quality if I post it as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A script loaded within a function call will only work within the immediate scope of where `require` or `include` was used. So really only variables present when `load_template()` is called will be accessible to the loaded script (unless you use `global $myvar` of course).

The reason vars like `$post` and `$wp_query` are available to the script is because `load_template()` globals them in before loading the script.

If you wanted to make sure your script can access certain vars, either `global` them in or add them to the `$wp_query->query_vars` array before loading (*not recommended but depending on the task it might be the only feasible option*), as those get extracted into the local scope before loading the script.